# unittest, assert if one of two values is in a string

Tags: python, unit-testing, python-unittest

Assuming a string of "string" I want my test to pass if one of "x" or "y" passes. If both fail - the test fails.
This is what I tried:

```
def check_if_x_or_y_in_string(self):
        self.assertIn("x", "given string")
        self.assertIn("y", "given string")
```

It keep failing because only one of them can be correct, the other always fails.

Appreciate the help.

Comment: Just use `assertTrue("x" in s or "y" in s)`.

Comment: got damn it, why didnt i think of that. thank you

Answer (score 0):

assertTrue("x" in s or "y" in s).
– MrBean Bremen